# How to find the frequent sub-sequence of base pairs of a given length

Tags: python, dictionary

> Find the most frequent sub-sequence of base pairs of a given length. 
>   Provided that the string and length is given

Example:

```
>>> most_freq_seq("AAGTTAGTCA", 3)
"AGT"
```

Can someone explain what "sub-sequence of base pair" means?

Comment: "base pairs" as in DNA?  Do you have an example of the sort of input that you're working with?

Comment: Please refer https://m.imgur.com/a/E9b9qiK

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) Also check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thank you,I will go through it

Comment: An image of text is useless on Stack Overflow. Are we supposed to re-type it, when copying it from your post would make it so much easier to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code if there are zero repetition the 1st given number of sequence will be displayed. it can changed by editing the second line of code to 
most_seq = "no repetiotion" or something

```
def most_freq_seq(sequence,seq_len):
    most_seq = sequence[0:seq_len]
    number = 1
    for i in range(0,len(sequence)-seq_len):
        val = sequence.count(sequence[i:i+seq_len])
        if val > number :
            number = val
            most_seq = sequence[i:i+seq_len]
    print(most_seq)

most_freq_seq("AAGTTAGTCA",3)
```

Comment: This function will find find frequent substrings, but it won't find non-contiguous subsequences. If I run it with `most_freq_seq("AGCTACGT",3)`, it prints `AGC` instead of `AGT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Counter class from collection combined with zip to get the subsequences:

```
from collections import Counter
def most_freq_seq(seq,count):
    counts = Counter("".join(s) for s in zip(*(seq[i:] for i in range(count))))
    return counts.most_common(1)[0]
```

output:

```
r,c = most_freq_seq("AAGTTAGTCA", 3)

print(r,c)
# 'AGT' 2
```

I know DNA sequences are very long but I believe this will provide results in reasonable time.

For a sequence of 10 million entries, I get the result in roughly 3 seconds using random data:

```
import random
import time

sequence = "".join(random.choice("ACGT") for _ in range(10_000_000))
size     = 7

start = time.time()
seq,count = most_freq_seq(sequence,size)
print(seq,count,time.time()-start)

# CCCAATT 704 3.12
```

Answer (score 0):

The input you're being given is a fragment of DNA.  Each letter corresponds to one of four "base pairs": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_pair

A "sub-sequence of base pairs" is therefore simply a substring -- that is, a smaller string that appears in the input string.  In the example you're given, "AGT" is a substring that appears twice (which is more often than any other substring that's 3 characters long, making it the most frequent):

```
AAGTTAGTCA
 AGT AGT
```

Your task is to implement the `most_freq_seq` function that will produce the most frequent substring of a given length from within the given string.  The fact that it's a string of DNA and that the characters are "base pairs" doesn't really affect the implementation.

Good luck!